# React calls api thousands of times inside a useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I am building a ToDoList with React and a Django rest Api but I am also using a Datepicker to render all the tasks for the day by the date created. But every time the site loads the api is called thousands of times. The goal would be to only render the tasks for the specific day when the date is changed or a new task for the day is added and not call the backend constalnly the problem seams to lay at the ToDoList because evertwhere else the props.date is only called once and not in a loop.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import 'date-fns'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns'
import{
    MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
    KeyboardTimePicker,
    KeyboardDatePicker
} from '@material-ui/pickers'
import TodoForm from '../ToDo/TodoForm'


function Datepicker() {
    const initialDate = new Date(Date.now())
    const [selectDate, setSelectDate] = useState(
        `${initialDate.getFullYear()}-${initialDate.getMonth()+1}-${initialDate.getDate()}`
    )
    
    const handleDateChange = (date) =>{
        setSelectDate(`${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}`)
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
        <div>
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <Grid container justify='space-around'>
                <KeyboardDatePicker
                    disableToolbar
                    varient='inline'
                    format='MM/dd/yy'
                    margin='normal'
                    id='date-picker'
                    label='Pick your Date'
                    value={selectDate}
                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                    KeyboradButtonProps={{
                        'aris-label': 'change date'
                    }}
                />
            </Grid>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        </div>
        <div>
           <TodoForm date={selectDate}/> 
        </div>
        </div>
    
        
    )
}

export default Datepicker
```

```
import React, { Component, useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import { apiTaskCreate } from './lookup'
import { ActionBtn } from './buttons'
import TodoList from './TodoList'

function TodoForm(props) {
    const [newTasks, setNewTasks] = useState([])
    const [taskname, SetTaskname] = useState('')
    const [Importants, setImportants] = useState({})
    const [TimeComplete, setTimeComplete] = useState({})
    

    
    const handleChange = e => {
        SetTaskname(e.target.value)
    }
    
    function onChangeImportants(value){
        setImportants(value.value)
        
    }
    function onChangeTimeComplete(value){
        setTimeComplete(value.value)
    }

    const handleSubmit = e =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        SetTaskname('')
        
        let tempNewTasks = [...newTasks]
        apiTaskCreate(taskname,Importants,TimeComplete,(response, status)=>{
            // console.log(response, status)
            if (status === 201){
                tempNewTasks.unshift(response)
                setNewTasks(tempNewTasks)
              } else {
                console.log(response)
                alert("an error accourd")
              }
        })

        
       
        
    }
    
    const Importants_options = [
        { value: '1', label: 1 },
        { value: '2', label: 2 },
        { value: '3', label: 3 },
        { value: '4', label: 4 },
        { value: '5', label: 5 },
      ]
    const Time_options = [
        { value: '1', label: 30 },
        { value: '2', label: 60 },
        { value: '3', label: 90 },
        { value: '4', label: 120 },
        { value: '5', label: 150 },
        { value: '6', label: 180 },
      ]

    return (
        
        <div className={props.className}>
        <div className='col-11 mb-3'>
          <form className='todo-form mb-3' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type='text' value={taskname} placeholder='Task Name' 
                name='task_name' className='todo-input' onChange={handleChange}></input>
            <Select onChange={onChangeImportants} options={Importants_options} placeholder="Importants Score"/>
            <Select onChange={onChangeTimeComplete} options={Time_options} placeholder="Time to complete"/>
            <button className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
            <ActionBtn action={{type: 'optimize', display:"Optimize"}}/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className='container'>
          <TodoList newTasks={newTasks} {...props}/>
      </div>
    
    
    
    </div>  
        
    )
}

export default TodoForm
```

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { apiTaskList } from './lookup'
import Task from './Task'


function TodoList(props) {
    const [tasksInit, setTasksInit] = useState([])
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])
    const [tasksDidSet, setTasksDidSet] = useState(false)
    const initialDate = new Date(Date.now())
    const [date, setDate] = useState("2021-04-12")

    // `${initialDate.getFullYear()}-${initialDate.getMonth()+1}-${initialDate.getDate()}`
    
    
    

    useEffect( () =>{
        const final = [...props.newTasks].concat(tasksInit)
        if (final.length !== tasks.length) {
            setTasks(final)
        }
        
      }, [props.newTasks, tasks, tasksInit])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (tasksDidSet === false) {
          const handleTasksListLookup = (response, status) => {
            if (status === 200) {
              setTasksInit(response)
              setDate(props.date)
              console.log(date)
            }
          }
          apiTaskList("admin", date ,handleTasksListLookup)
        }
    }, [tasksInit, setTasksDidSet, setTasksDidSet, date])


    return tasks.map((item, index)=>{
        return <Task task={item} className='d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border bg-white text-dark' key={`${index}-${item.id}`}/>
      })
        
}

export default TodoList;
```

```
import { backendlookup } from "../lookup/lookup";




export function apiTaskCreate(newTask_Name,newImportans_Score,newTime_to_complete,callback) {
    backendlookup('POST', 'create',callback, {
      Task_name: newTask_Name,
      Importants_Score: newImportans_Score,
      Time_to_Finish: newTime_to_complete,
    }) 
}

export function apiTaskList(username,date,callback) {
    let endpoint = 'tasks'
    
    if (date){
        endpoint = `tasks?username=${username}&date=${date}`
    }
    backendlookup('GET', endpoint ,callback)  
}

export function apiPartyActionOptimize(action,callback) {
    backendlookup('POST', 'action-optimize',callback, {action:action})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a dependency to useEffect which itself is being updated inside it. If you do so, your useEffect execution will go into an infinite loop.

You can make use of functional version of setState to update the tasks state.

Your updated code will look as follows

```
useEffect( () =>{
    const final = [...props.newTasks].concat(tasksInit);
    setTasks(tasks => {
       if (final.length !== tasks.length) {
          return final;
        }
        return tasks
    });
    
    
  }, [props.newTasks, tasksInit])

useEffect(() => {
    if (tasksDidSet === false) {
      const handleTasksListLookup = (response, status) => {
        if (status === 200) {
          setTasksInit(response);
          setDate(props.date);
        }
      }
      apiTaskList("admin", date ,handleTasksListLookup)
    }
}, [setTasksInit, props.date, tasksDidSet])
```

Comment: This gets rid of the refreshing but the date is never refreshed and so the list stays the same. the only thing that causes a change is the tasksInit but that also causes the constant refreshes

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `setTasks` method inside the `useEffect` function it updates the `tasks` value and because you have the `tasks` variable as one of the dependencies in the `useEffect` callback, the API gets called indefinitely. Remove `tasks` from the `useEffect` dependency and it should work.